# Error when populating table view with coredata

Tags: iphone

I am working with coredata and successfully saved the data in data storage but when I try to output what I stored using table view ,I am not able to do it.

Here the user will enter and click save ..so when he goes back..I want the table to populated with what name he or she has entered.

So I wrote the below code for saving and find data:

```
- (void) saveData
{
    coredata123AppDelegate *appDelegate = 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = 
    [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    Contacts *newContact;
    newContact = [NSEntityDescription
                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts"
                  inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newContact setValue:name.text forKey:@"name"];
    [newContact setValue:address.text forKey:@"address"];
    [newContact setValue:phone.text forKey:@"phone"];
    name.text = @"";
    address.text = @"";
    phone.text = @"";
    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];
    status.text = @"Contact saved";    
}

- (void) findContact
{
    coredata123AppDelegate *appDelegate = 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = 
    [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = 
    [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contacts" 
                inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];
    NSPredicate *pred = 
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name = %@)", 
     name.text];
    [request setPredicate:pred];
    NSManagedObject *matches = nil;
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request 
                                              error:&error];

    for(Contacts *info in objects)
    {
        NSLog(@"Name:%@",info.name);
        NSLog(@"Address:%@",info.address);
    }   
    if ([objects count] == 0) {
        status.text = @"No matches";
    } else {
        matches = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
        address.text = [matches valueForKey:@"address"];
        phone.text = [matches valueForKey:@"phone"];
        status.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                       @"%d matches found", [objects count]];
    }
    [request release];


}
```

And to populate the table view i have written this code..

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                                   entityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    self.contacts = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    [fetchRequest release];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


    Contacts *info =[contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text =info.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=info.address;

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: hello friends please reply.......m waiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting proper number of elements in this objects array?

```
NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request 
                                          error:&error];
```

if not, try changing the predicate with,

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name=%@", name.text];
```

Otherwise, your code seems correct to me.

Comment: ya karim..i get proper number of elements in the array

Comment: hello everyone..please help me out in finding how to output the data on to the table view....

Comment: i am getting this error reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Contacts''
*** Call stack at first throw:

Comment: If it cannot find out 'Contacts' entity, how can you get the proper number of elements in the array? Check if your table/entity name is correct or not.

Comment: ya its correct...karim...karim what i want is in my first page their is a empty tableview ,an textfield and a searchbutton....so when the user press the search button he navigates to tableview with all values populated from the server,so now when he clicks on specific cell again a diffrent page opens with some details of the entity in the cell and also it will show the name of the entity presses on the label..now,here i will provide one button on navigation bar by title "favorite",so when he clicks that button and goes back to first view he gets that entity in the table..

Comment: You first view contains the list from the server or the list in favorites? Since everything seems correct, try [self.tableView reloadData] in the viewWillAppear method.

Comment: my first view contains list from favorites